# How to Crawl only particular tables from rds db

Tags: aws-glue

I am trying to load rds(postgresql) tables into glue catalog using crawler. Is there any way to load only the required tables from rds?

I have 120 tables in my rds schema. I need only two tables (ex: emp and market tables).

Answer (score 0):

Yes. When creating your crawler in the 'Data Store' step, you will need to use one of the below (see screenshot too):

1. `Include path` to include 1 regex pattern.
2. `Exclude patters` to exclude 1-to-many regex patterns.
3. Note all supported regex patterns can be found [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/define-crawler.html#crawler-data-stores-exclude)

[image]